# CSS rules for browsers, font size EM for some divs

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-size

I have some divs that in mobile devices and different browsers, like, Internet Explorer and Mozilla, under Samsung galaxy S6, shows not the same font-size.

**I´m working with EM**: yes, maybe it´s not the best but I like it and I feel comfortable with this.

**Is there some CSS hack or way (not javascript) to define several rules depend the browser.**

For example (and I will do it on each div, not as set)

```
.divone
{
font-size: 20em;
}
If its Mozilla... .divone { }
If its Explorer... .divone { }
```

And I think that I also have to conserve the first declaration, .divone if it is not Mozilla or Explorer.

**Anyone knows how?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not javascript? how about **php**

**get**

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
```

**compare & set css**

```
 if(strlen(strstr($agent,"Firefox")) > 0 ){      
        $browser = 'firefox';
    }
    if($browser=='firefox'){
        echo '<style type="text/css" href="firefox-font-style.css"/>';
    }
```

The add a file firefox-font-style.css with your styles for only firfox

Comment: I was thinking in a lazy (easy) way but you gave me a great suggestion.
Is there a way to detect if it´s Internet Explorer regardless the version… 6,7,8,9, etc… 
Thanks you!

Comment: `<!--[if IE]>something here<![endif]-->`